# How does a typical, healthy Google Search Console history look like?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

The following is a snapshot of my website's Google Search console history in the past 6 months. Unfortunately, I don't have any reference to understand whether this looks bad, healthy/typical, or even great. Based on your experience working with different sites, would you say this is a bad, typical, or great progress?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Much of the answer depends upon the site itself.

For example, a few of my sites should not see much traffic at all. For example, one is for my apartment building. Short of a few pages of content intended to help tenants, there is no real reason to visit the site unless you are looking for an apartment. Another is for an antiques business site. It is one page.

I get very little traffic on both. However, what is important is the quality of the traffic you receive and how it converts to customers. As for my apartments, I actually get tenants before having an opening. As for the antiques site, people have driven from Oregon to Pennsylvania and dropped $2000 on a Saturday. We often get people from Pittsburgh which is 2 hours away. The apartment site only gets about 60 page views a month and ranks #1 for searches in my area. The antiques site, much less page views but still performs well in search. The apartment site gets 4-5 page views per user. This is far above average for such a site.

My point is this. Traffic is good depending upon the site. However, not all sites need or should expect much traffic. What is most important is the quality of the traffic and how the traffic converts. Too many people try and rank for too much. For my example sites, I only need to rank for a fairly narrow search. For example, "apartments near me" or "antiques near me" or "apartments in [*town*] Pennsylvania". I get all the traffic for these searches and more and therefore dominate the market.

It all depends upon your goal.

Answer (score 2):

The total number of clicks and total impressions are fluctuating, but overall they are moving upwards, which is a good thing. It will increase once the average position improves and CTR increases.

The CTR seems to be on the lower end of the spectrum. It can be improved by optimising for relevant keywords to reach the desired customer segment and further increased by improving **meta titles and description.**

Average position improved from June to September but is starting to flatline. (Can be improved with better SEO).